# Swift upside down orientation not working

Tags: orientation

I have added these methods to my view controller:
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .all
}
```

But still the upside down orientation is not working.

Any other pointers what could be missing.
This info has been added to info.plist as well as to the target.